# How do you find the maximum number in a list without using the function "max"?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, max

I'm a beginner at programming, and I'm trying to create a program that generates 1000 random numbers, and then prints out the highest value of the numbers in the list of numbers (I am aware that my program only outputs 10 numbers, it is because I'm trying to debug the program). I already have a program, but it's not working. The problem is, the program will output these seemingly random numbers, sometimes its the largest number, and other times its a list of more than one number. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import random
num_list=[]
largest=[]
maximum=-1
while len(num_list)<10:
    numbers=random.randrange(0,11)
    numbers=int(float(numbers))
    num_list.append(numbers)
if len(num_list)==10:
    print num_list
    for num in num_list:
        if num>maximum:
            maximum=num
            largest.append(num)
    print largest
```

Comment: Sort the list then take the last element: `num_list.sort()` then `maximum=num_list[-1]`. If you don't want to modify the list in-place use `sorted(num_list)` to make a sorted copy.

Comment: Actually, it raises an error on `maximum.append()` because maximum is an int. You are close, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient way of doing this:

```
numList = []
for i in range(10):
    numList.append(random.randrange(0,11))

maxNum = -1
for i in numList:
    if i > maxNum:
        maxNum = i

print(maxNum)
```

Comment: You can even exchange the top 3 lines for this:

   num_list = [random.randrange(0,11) for i in range(10)]

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense

```
        maximum=num
        maximum.append(num)
```

perhaps you mean this

```
        maximum=num
        largest.append(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x if x > y else y, [random.randrange(0,11) for i in range(10)])
```